# Detect backbutton pressed in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to detect backbutton pressed in Fragment.

My app start download data in Fragment, so I need to stop download (also do some operations) on back button pressed, and dont need if home button pressed. So I cant use onPause(), because its called in both cases.

I use addToBackStack(null), but I need to do some operations (stop download and ) in current fragment and then return to previous fragment.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
   .beginTransaction()
   .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
   .addToBackStack(null)
   .commit();
```

Comment: do it in your fragment's onDestroyView()

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with the things you want to do in the fragment you could use something like this to remove the current fragment. If last fragment was added to the stack (as you mentioned) then removing current fragment will automatically display last fragment.

```
this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .remove(this).commit();
```

or

```
this.getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .remove(this).commit();
```

Comment: Thank you. But I dont need to remove fragment.

Comment: Then how would you return to the last fragment when you are done with current fragment if you dont want to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing)
On yout activity you can overide onBackPressed() et then call popBackStack

Comment: ok! if you use asyncTask, on your onPause method you can can asyncTask.cancel().
if you want to do a specific job, AsyncTask call onCancelled() when you call asyncTask.cancel(). Override it!